# Как передать результат себе на сайт?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

```
 function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1c9JP0KSgOqIcewJHLYoo796WdvkOIfjDBBORnlFR3Os");
  var n = sheet.getRange("U1").getValue()+1;
  var time = sheet.getRange("C"+n).getValue();
  var phone = sheet.getRange("E"+n).getValue();
  sheet.getRange("U1").setValue(n);
  return 1;
}
```

Пишет, что Скрипт был выполнен, но возвращение значения не относится к поддерживаемому типу.

http://joxi.ru/D2PegJRuvY1xA3 - вот скрин.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень долго искал способ, как передавать данные из google spreadsheets при появлении новых строк.

Надеюсь, что кому-нибудь окажется полезным.

[Здесь решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539532/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-php-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E)