# Как из Spreadsheets передать переменную в php файл на другом сервере.

Tags: php, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Хочу передать phone.
Запрос отправляется, но переменная не передаётся.

```
 function doGet(e)
    {
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1K_mDfo6fUpfv2t8BL5jOcSbcxZLQAeBjhuRDbv7wkG0");
      var n=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()+2;
      var d = new Date(); 
      sheet.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
      sheet.getRange("B"+n).setValue('1');
      sheet.getRange("C"+n).setValue('2');
      sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(n-1);
      var options =
       {
         "method" : "post",
         "phone" : 'a',
       };

       UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://sotvorec.com/form_action/task.php", options);
    }
```

Comment: Какую переменную куда вытянуть? Нужны подробности, не понятно по вашему коду

Comment: Нужно было вытянуть переменную phone.

а в task.php эта переменная вытягивается так:
$a = $_POST['phone'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function doGet(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1K_mDfo6fUpfv2t8BL5jOcSbcxZLQAeBjhuRDbv7wkG0");
  var n=sheet.getRange("A1").getValue()+2;
  var d = new Date(); 
  sheet.getRange("A"+n).setValue(d);
  sheet.getRange("B"+n).setValue('1');
  sheet.getRange("C"+n).setValue('2');
  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(n-1);
var payload =
   {
     "phone" : phone,
   };

  var options =
   {
     "method" : "post",
     "payload" : payload
   };

   UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://sotvorec.com/form_action/task.php", options);
}
```